# SoftInputMode adjustResize don't work when setVisibility is called

Tags: android, android-fragments, window-soft-input-mode

I have an issue, i have a fragment with some elements. I have buttons in the bottom (signup_step_buttons) i would like they stay on the top of the keyboard. But when i `setVisibility VISIBLE` to all elements the **adjustResize** work, but when i `setVisibility GONE` (to **backStep** & **validForm**). When the keyboard appear, the layout is not adapted... So i found the problem (seems to be the visibility of elements in the layout) but i don't know how to fix it ...

**Edit :** the issue come from `setVisibility`, whatever the value setted... Just when i call it the **adaptResize** is not applied.

My fragment Layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
style="@style/Aidodys.Activity.AuthActivity.SignUp">
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/signup_step_top_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/sign_up_close"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_close_light_cross"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_signup_close_step"/>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/signup_step_indicator"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/sign_up_close"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/signup_valid_form"
    android:layout_above="@+id/signup_step_buttons"
    android:gravity="center">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/signup_valid_form_button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        style="@style/Aidodys.ButtonWhite.Steps.ValidForm"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/signup_valid_form_button"
        android:text="@string/text_agree_cgu"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Aidodys.Button.Little.Text.Blue"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/signup_step_buttons"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signup_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        style="@style/Aidodys.ButtonWhite.Steps.Back"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signup_next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        style="@style/Aidodys.ButtonWhite.Steps.Next"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_below="@id/signup_step_top_bar"
    android:layout_above="@id/signup_valid_form"
    android:id="@+id/signup_fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></FrameLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

And my Fragment class :

```
public class SignUpFragment extends Fragment {
/**
 * Id to identity READ_CONTACTS permission request.
 */
private static final int REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 0;

/**
 * Keep track of the login task to ensure we can cancel it if requested.
 */

// UI references.
private AidodysRequest aidodysRequest;
private SignUpRequestObject object;
private Button nextStep;
private Button backStep;
private int step;
private int stepMax = 5;
private ImageView stepIndicator;
private StepEmailFragment emailStep;
private StepNameFragment nameStep;
private StepPasswordFragment passwordStep;
private StepCategoryFragment categoryStep;
private StepCountryFragment countryStep;
private RelativeLayout      validForm;
private Fragment[]          steps = new Fragment[stepMax];
private Drawable[]          indicator = new Drawable[stepMax];

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
    ((AuthActivity)getActivity()).setOnBackPressedListener(new AuthActivity.OnBackPressedListener() {
        @Override
        public void doBack() {
            if (step <= 0) {
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            } else {
                step--;
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (step < 1)
                            backStep.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        stepIndicator.setImageDrawable(indicator[step]);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
    return (inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_signup, container, false));

}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    aidodysRequest = new AidodysRequest(getActivity());
    object = new SignUpRequestObject();

    indicator[0] = getActivity().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_step_indicator_1);
    indicator[1] = getActivity().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_step_indicator_2);
    indicator[2] = getActivity().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_step_indicator_3);
    indicator[3] = getActivity().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_step_indicator_4);
    indicator[4] = getActivity().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_step_indicator_5);

    stepIndicator = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.signup_step_indicator);

    steps[0] = emailStep = new StepEmailFragment();
    steps[1] = nameStep = new StepNameFragment();
    steps[2] = passwordStep = new StepPasswordFragment();
    steps[3] = categoryStep = new StepCategoryFragment();
    steps[4] = countryStep = new StepCountryFragment();
    step = 0;

    stepIndicator.setImageDrawable(indicator[step]);
    getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.signup_fragment_container, steps[step])
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
    nextStep = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.signup_next);
    backStep = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.signup_back);
    validForm = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.signup_valid_form);

    backStep.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    validForm.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    emailStep.setOnEmailLookUpResponse(new StepEmailFragment.OnEmailLookUpResponse() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            ((ISignUpStep)steps[step]).saveData();
            getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(R.animator.enter_anim_right, R.animator.exit_anim_left, R.animator.enter_anim_left, R.animator.exit_anim_right)
                    .replace(R.id.signup_fragment_container, steps[++step])
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    backStep.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    stepIndicator.setImageDrawable(indicator[step]);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure() {

        }
    });
    emailStep.setAidodysRequest(aidodysRequest);
    nextStep.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (((ISignUpStep)steps[step]).checkData() && step < steps.length - 1) {
                ((ISignUpStep)steps[step]).saveData();
                if (step == steps.length - 2) {
                    validForm.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                getFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .setCustomAnimations(R.animator.enter_anim_right, R.animator.exit_anim_left, R.animator.enter_anim_left, R.animator.exit_anim_right)
                        .replace(R.id.signup_fragment_container, steps[++step])
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
                stepIndicator.setImageDrawable(indicator[step]);
            }
        }
    });

    backStep.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (step > 0) {
                --step;
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (step < 1)
                            backStep.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        if (step == steps.length - 3)
                            validForm.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        stepIndicator.setImageDrawable(indicator[step]);
                    }
                });
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: What type of values are you setting to GONE. Like EditTexts, TextViews, Buttons, etc?

Comment: A button and a relative layout, I see yesterday whatever the value I set, when I reach setVisibility that don't work...

Comment: It's probably the relative layout, I don't see why the button would affect this. I'm sure you can find an easy work around. just keep trying and researching.

Comment: I try on remove the relative layout so i setVisibility GONE only for the button and that's the same problem ... :(

Comment: When i lock my smartphone and unlock it and become on my fragment that work. So i try to call onResume onRestart.... No way ... that don't work. So maybe a solution is to refresh the activity or the fragment but .. How to do it ??